# Small project with multi login page one has select count 1 and the other has insert into

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Let me explain my small project so you can get my question it has multi login page in the log in page the SQL Server is select from, and in the other page insert into, so the user will give his request to the system. my question is i want to know how raised the request. Basically I want the Username from the Login page to be add to the insert into table for the users.

```
 if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlCon.Open();
                string query = "SELECT count (1) FROM Login WHERE Username=@Username AND password=@password AND usertype=@usertype";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
           if (checkbox1.IsChecked == true)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", checkbox1.Content.ToString());
            else if (checkbox2.IsChecked == true)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", checkbox2.Content.ToString());
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (count == 1)
            {
                if ((bool)checkbox1.IsChecked == true)
                {

                    MainWindow Dashboard = new MainWindow();
                    Dashboard.Show();
                    MessageBox.Show("You're logged in as an Admin");
                    this.Close();
                }

                if ((bool)checkbox2.IsChecked == true)
                {

                    Student stu = new Student();
                    stu.Show();
                    MessageBox.Show("You're logged in as a Student");

                    this.Close();
                 }
```

/// the other page (Requester page )

```
                var table = "INSERT INTO  Student(UserName,DepartureCiry,ArrivalCity,DateOfDeparture,DateOfReturn)VALUES(@UserName,@DepartureCiry,@ArrivalCity,@DateOfDeparture,@DateOfReturn)";
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(table, Con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartureCiry", fromtxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArrivalCity", Totxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfDeparture", date_time_picker.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfReturn", date_time_picker1.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data inserted suckssfully");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Side note: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @leo: I don't understand your question. What is the "requester page"?

Comment: @mm8 They are 3 pages on of them the login page with select from ( from the data base) and the other is the requester which is the student page it has insert into values i want to take the column ""Name"" from the login table and store it automatically in the student table with the insert into values ,,, i hope you got my question now

Comment: @leo: So you want to pass the name from the login page to the student page?

Comment: @mm8 yes i want it to be inserted in the student table so i can know who from the student made the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the username from the login page to the `Student` window.

There are several ways do to this. You could for example add a property to the `Student` window:

```
public string Username { get; set; }
```

And then set this property befor you open the window:

```
if ((bool)checkbox2.IsChecked == true)
{
    Student stu = new Student() { Username = txtUsername.Text };
    stu.Show();
    MessageBox.Show("You're logged in as a Student");
    this.Close();
}
```

You can then access `this.Username` to get the username in the `Student` window.

Comment: Thank you VERY much MR,MM8 this is the second time you actual help me with my project for that i'm very very appreciated . @mm8

Comment: Hi @mm8 can i ask you a small question regarding my project i tried to get the answer here but unfortunately couldn't i'm sure that you'll be able to help me instantly

Comment: @leo: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Feel free to add a link to the new question here.